# What does this macro function mean?

Tags: c++, c, macros

```
#define CONCAT(a,b) a##b
#define METHOD(method)    \
public:    \
static int CONCAT(method,wrapper)(int* ptri, char* ptrc, double* ptrd)    \
{    \
  return ((type *)ptri)->method(ptrc,ptrd);    \
}
```

Question 1: Is this METHOD something like a class or struct?

Question 2: For the

```
static int CONCAT(method,wrapper)(int* ptri, char* ptrc, double* ptrd)
```

does it mean:

```
static int methodwrapper(int* ptri, char* ptrc, double* ptrd)
```

Comment: To the computer, it means what it expands to.  You should ask the person who wrote it what its semantics are intended to be; we can't even begin to guess.  (Except insofar as I see at least one loaded footgun on almost every line.)

Comment: It means you likely have some code to rewrite, convenience macros might seem good during development, but they are maintenance nightmares,  try stepping through that in a debugger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing like that, it's just a way to obfuscate code (or write nearly the same thing over and over again in a lazy way)

The following

```
class X
{

    public: 
    static int SomeMethodwrapper(int * ptri, char* ptrc, double* ptrd)    
    {    
      return ((type *)ptri)->SomeMethod(ptrc,ptrd);    
    }
    public:    
    static int SomeOtherMethodwrapper(int * ptri, char* ptrc, double* ptrd)    
    {    
      return ((type *)ptri)->SomeOtherMethod(ptrc,ptrd);    
    }

};
```

can thus be written as

```
class X
{
    METHOD(SomeMethod)
    METHOD(SomeOtherMethod)
};
```

Comment: To be fair, this appears to be an interface for exposing C++ class methods to C code - the kind of thing where the obfuscation doesn't matter so much and macros _can_ make it more robust. Of course, the idea that C code is doing stuff with C++ object pointers cast to `int *` somewhat undermines any notion of robustness...

Comment: @Notlikethat I don't see how this code can expose class members to C. there's no `public` in C.

Comment: As a side note, this is exactly what occurs when you use Microsoft's COM macros.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I'm imagining C++ objects passing methods to C code as callbacks, but there may be more evil header trickery we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

As it follows from the name of the macro it simply concatenates two tokens, For example

```
CONCAT( class, Method )
```

results in

```
classMethod
```

As for macro #define METHOD(method) then it defines a static public method and uses macro CONCAT to form the name of the method.